# In Pyspark using Python - Row wise check one particular column if it contains a list of keywords. If yes, copy the matched keyword/s to another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `StringType` column in a DataFrame. For each row of that particular column of the DataFrame, I want to check if it contains the keywords mentioned in another column of the DataFrame. If yes, then it will fill the matched keyword in that row of a new column.

Each row of the `DESCRIPTION` column in my `df` looks something like this:-

```
"cs1copdbq01ha - AIX ERRPT problem - resource name:hdisk5 errpt entry:HARDWARE:CRITICAL:PA,;BNS_Unix;Â Â  Â MajorÂ Â  Â bns_cs1copdbq01haÂ Â  Â AIX ERRPT problem"
```

For every row in `DESCRIPTION` column, I want to check if any of the following Names in `NAMES` column appear in it. Partial or Full match. If appears, then the name or names which matched should get filled in another column named `MATCH` of the same DataFrame. If not it should fill `'No Name'` to the `MATCH` column.

```
+--------+
|   NAMES|
+--------+
|   drake|
|   BRAke|
|    Jake|
|    Ktac|
|    Dake|
|    Howy|
|    Briy|
|    Vesi|
+--------+
```